# Why is my WPF datagrid background colour not binding?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm using an MVVM approach. I've got a datagrid with columns for the days of the week. I ned to highlight the current day with a shaded background. Everything else in the viewmodel is displaying properly so it's binding in general. However, the shading is never applied and if I put breakpoints in my properties, the breakpoints are never hit. I'm doing something stupid but can't spot what.

Here's my code for the colours in the viewmodel:

```
  public Brush SundayColor { get { return GetBrushColorForWeekday(DayOfWeek.Sunday); } }

    public Brush MondayColor { get { return GetBrushColorForWeekday(DayOfWeek.Monday); } }

    public Brush TuesdayColor { get { return GetBrushColorForWeekday(DayOfWeek.Tuesday); } }

    public Brush WednesdayColor { get { return GetBrushColorForWeekday(DayOfWeek.Wednesday); } }

    public Brush ThursdayColor { get { return GetBrushColorForWeekday(DayOfWeek.Thursday); } }

    public Brush FridayColor { get { return GetBrushColorForWeekday(DayOfWeek.Friday); } }

    public Brush SaturdayColor { get { return GetBrushColorForWeekday(DayOfWeek.Saturday); } }

    private Brush GetBrushColorForWeekday(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
    {
        return dayOfWeek == CurrentDate.DayOfWeek ? Brushes.AliceBlue : Brushes.White;
    }
```

For the grid XAML I'm using the following. To make it brief I've shown one column definition only but the other six are similar:

```
   <DataGridTextColumn Header="Mon" Width="33" Binding="{Binding MondayQuantity,NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}">
        <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding MondayColor}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
```

I know the styles work as if I change the binding to a fixed colour I see the chosen colour. So why aren't my bindings working?

### EDIT

I was being stupid! The colour properties are in my viewmodel directly, not in the items that the grid is bound to.

Is it possible to bind the grid styles to items from the viewmodel that are outside of the observablecolleciton the grid is bound to? I suppose, "one level up" is what I'm after:

viewmodel

- mondaycolor, etc. <-- bind style to this
- items observablecollection <-- data in grid is from this

  - quantities

Comment: I think you don't want to have anything related to the view in your ViewModel, e.g. the colors of your cells. Insted you can define them in the view using triggers or a binding with a converter.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to do this for my situation?

Comment: Your binding works for me. Do you see any binding error messages in VS output window?

Comment: Ah, yes! Errors. Of course, my colours are in the viewmodel but not in the observablecollection items that make up the grid. How did I not spot that?!

Comment: Richard, go ahead for @franssu's converter approach. That saves you a lot of properties in your model/item class.

Comment: That still needs the "higher level" binding though, which I don't know how to do.

Comment: You can achieve "higher level binding" by adding a reference to the parent ViewModel in the class of the items listed by your collection. But still, you shouldn't have brushes or anything that is purely view related in your VM.

Comment: @Richard The converter approach *does not require* the "higher level" binding, since - provided that `CurrentData` is a static variable - the converter won't care at all for the binding source object. It simply returns the proper Brush, no matter what binding it is used in.

Comment: It depends if CurrentDate is static or not...

Comment: @franssu I don't get what you mean with "it depends". Your converter simply ignores the `value` argument. So whatever the binding source is, it returns one of two brushes, depending solely on the `parameter` argument.

Comment: @franssu - CurrentDate is a viewmodel property. It's not actually DateTime.Now as the "current date" can be changed. (Don't ask)

Comment: @Clemens It didn't use the value argument because my guess was that CurrentDate was static. If it is not static, you have to pass it through binding and then get it through the value parameter of the converter's convert function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm used to using converters so... I'm thinking about something like that (psoeudo-code)

Xaml:

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Parameter="Monday",
                                      Converter={StaticResource currentDayToColorCOnverter}}"/>
```

Converter:

```
class CurrentyDayToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(blablabla, .., object parameter)
    {
        if (CurrentDate.DayOfWeek == parameter) // may not be exactly that but you get the idea
        {
             return Brushes.AliceBlue;
        }
        else
        { 
              return Brushes.White
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @pchajer That is nonsense. You can very well bind the `Background` property to an object of type `Brush`, since `Background` is itself of type `Brush` (not "color object"). The default converter is only applied if the source value is a string.

Comment: It depends where CurrentDate comes from. If it's a global static class, you don't need to care about the source.

Comment: As it is (i.e. source not defined), the whole datacontext is passed through the binding and I think the converter is called when the component is loaded.

Comment: @franssu CurrentDate is a value in the viewmodel

Comment: I've marked this as correct as it fixes my initial question, though not the problem I ended up with through my own stupidity :)